# UiPageViewController Images

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

Hello I need to display images in a UIPageViewController but I have problems with that

I have a NSMutableArray with all images but I need help on how to visualize

I have this code

```
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *dataObject;




array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                 nil];
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should read some tutorial about the  `UIPageController`. There is plenty of them. The following tutorial show you almost exactly what you need:

http://www.ioslearner.com/tag/uipageviewcontroller-demo/

If you will have some more specific question feel free to ask.